# How to use regex to capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

**`tel:+13172221234;foo=1234;bar=000-000-000;wombat=mydomain.com`**

Note that the string always begins with `tel:+{{some-number}}`. I want to capture so that I have the following:

```
+13172221234
foo
1234
bar
000-000-000
wombat
mydomain.com
```

What I have is this: **`([^?=&;]+)=([^;]*)`** which returns three matches, each with a variable and a value (i.e., foo/1234). However I cannot seem to capture the number in front. I would think that simply putting a `tel:(\w+)` in front would do it but it doesn't work.

https://regex101.com/r/cM2pQ5/2

Anyone able to help? Maybe I should just do two separate regexes?

Comment: Which programming language you were using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one more way: ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cM2pQ5/6))

```
^tel:([^;]+)|;([^=]+)=([^;]+)
```

This has two parts - the first part only matches the start of the string and the second part matches the rest of the key value pairs. I'm assuming that your string starts with `tel:`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
([^:?=&;]+)(?=[=;])(?:=([^;]*))?
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(             # Start of capture group #1
   [^:?=&;]+  # Match 1 or more char of anything but ? or = or & or ;
)             # End of capture group #1
(?=           # Start of positive lookahead
   [=;]       # to assert next position is either = or ;
)             # End of positive lookahead
(?:           # Start of "optional" non-capturing group
   =          # match literal =
   (          # Start of capture group #2
      [^;]*   # match 0 or more of any char that is not a ;
   )          # End of capture group #2
)?            # Start of non-capturing group. ? in the end makes it optional
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM2pQ5/5)

Comment: You don't match the `tel`, is it intended?

Comment: Right because `tel` is not in the expected output list of OP.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Not exactly sure what it's doing ;) I'm going to have to dig into lookaheads.

Comment: Glad you liked it but a bit surprised to see the answer you've accepted. You never mentioned in question that your input will always have `tel:` are line start as I didn't take that liberty in building my regex here.

Comment: The author above *explained* how they got the answer. That's important for me and other people who come across this post in the future. I still don't have a decent explanation of your regex here.

Comment: I've added an explanation in my answer. The demo link I had provided had this explanation as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you can face or `=` or `:` as a Key/Value separator I suggest this:

```
([^?=&;]+)(=|:)([^;]*)
```

Comment: ``you can face or = or : as a key/value pair`` -- could you explain that? This works, although I don't need the ``:`` or ``=`` to turn up in the results.

Comment: @Jeff your key is the first part: `Tel`, `Foo`, `Bar`. The Value is, well, the value it has... Like in a Dictionary

Comment: Oh, you meant I can *use* ``=`` or ``:`` as kv separator. I was confused about the word ``face``.

Comment: @Jeff : sorry, my English is still under construction :p

Answer (score 1):

I would simply match this:

```
[^;=]+
```